# WP No reconoce mi archivo taxonomy.php

Tags: php, wordpress

estoy registrando varias taxonomías para un CPT pero no todas se pueden apreciar con el archivo `taxonomy.php`, es decir, algunas abren y se aprecian en `taxonomy.php` correctamente, pero otras me lanzan un `error 404` en vez de mostrarse en `taxonomy.php`.

He creado varios archivos `taxonomy.php` personalizados para tratar de abrir cada taxonomía en su propio archivo y tampoco funciona como se espera, ya que solamente abre 01 página y las otras no, a pesar de tener los archivos nombrados correctamente.

De alguna manera wp no está "detectando" que efectivamente existe un archivo `taxonomy.php` para mostrar TODAS las taxonomías y no solo algunas.

Lo que espero es que al menos se abran en mi `taxonomy.php` "genérico" o cuando menos que abran en su propio `taxonomy-tax_name.php` (tengo ambos archivos).

Para registrar las taxonomias estoy usando `CPT UI`, al igual que lo hice con los `Custom Post Types`.

¿A alguien más le ha sucedido? ¿Alguien tiene una idea de tal anomalía? Si hace falta más información con mucho gusto la haré llegar. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Si a alguien "no le funciona" el archivo taxonomy.php esta puede ser una posible causa/solucion:

Acabo de resolver mi problema. El problema estaba en la `Reescritura personalizada de slug`, resulta que como todas esas `taxonomías` pertenecen al mismo `CPT`, opté en un principio por renombrar el slug a todas por igual, es decir, mis 6 taxonomías tenian como slug personalizado `"items"`.

Al remover el slug personalizado y después de entrar a enlaces permanentes / guardar (sin modificar nada), inmediatamente fueron cargados los taxonomy-custom.php que habia creado e incluso en mis pruebas, también cargaron todas en el archivo taxonomy.php genérico.